# Network printer no longer printing anything other than Test Page

Tags: networking, printing

As of today, my printer just stopped working.
As soon as I submit a job, it is either immediately set as "completed" or it remains in "processing" for ever.

What change was recently made in Ubuntu LTS w.r.t. network printing? Because nothing changed on my end.

```
bram@ubuntupc:~$ lpstat -p
printer RICOH-Aficio-SP-3510DN is idle.  enabled since Tue 26 Mar 2019 09:58:08 AM PDT
bram@ubuntupc:~$ lpc status
RICOH-Aficio-SP-3510DN:
    printer is on device 'dnssd' speed -1
    queuing is enabled
    printing is enabled
    no entries
    daemon present
```

And to make matters worse, after trying to "modify printer" it now will no longer show jobs in the CUPS web page either:

[image]

Also, why is it discovered twice, and the current connection different from both?

[image]

"Print Test Page" works (most of the time, I've also had it fail.)

What the heck... .this used to be a perfectly reliable printer. I suspect an Ubuntu software change.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with Inkscape instead.

I removed and added the printer to the OS again. After which, printing from inkscape would make the printer warm up, and then not print anything.

If I export an inkscape SVG document and print the resulting PNG file with GIMP, the printer would actually print.

So this was a case of Inkscape not being able to print, although it would generate jobs in the queue, and would make the printer warm up.